# Creating a secure SOAP service proxy with WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2

From what I've read and experienced, the API Manager 1.3.1 only generates  proxies. However, I would like to proxy a back-end SOAP service with a  SOAP service proxy and have the proxy implement a WS-Policy with a WS-SecurityPolicy.

Is there built-in support for this in API Manager 1.3.1?

Will there be support for this in the next version of API Manager?

If no, then what steps would I take to have the API Publisher and Store apps recognize SOAP  proxies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in wso2esb, itself contains throttling [1]/analytics[2] support.You can check the documentation on how to enable the throttling for proxies. If you like to use APIManager, define a proxy in another instance(like ESB) and provide that as endpoint when you create an API. But that proxy has to handle REST calls..
But from my understanding, you can simply use wso2esb.

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15471353

[2]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Statistics

Comment: I will use wso2esb to create a secure proxy that's an endpoint of an API in wso2am.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that API Manager is not the ideal way to start to implement your use case. You should use Enterprise Serivce bus which provides the UI and necessary other tools to implement the scenario.

You can install the required features (Which is pre installed in ESB) to API manager and use those features. But you can just go ahead with WSO2 ESB as it is.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB402/Secure+Proxy+Template

Comment: Thanks but I know this functionality exists in the ESB. What I'm really looking for is to leverage WSO2's throttling and API analytics features with secure SOAP proxies. The API Manager product makes this easy for REST proxies, but seemingly does not directly support SOAP.

I guess I'll start with the ESB and Registry products and then try to add on the throttling and analytics capabilities.